# Coding Nested Effect in gam() via Implicit Nesting

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, nested-data, nested-models

I'm trying to find the best specification of a nested mixed effects model using gam. I don't have an easy dataset to share, but simulate an example below - and have figure to help explain. Basically, if my data is coded for implicit nesting of a random effect, do I have to tell gam() the variable is nested?

I have multiple Sites sampled each year, each site contains a set of sample blocks (e.g. "A1:A5"). For a given day of sampling, every Site is included, but within each site I select a random subset of blocks to take samples from.

Therefore it is possible for individual sample blocks to be sampled multiple times, while others may not have been sampled at all.
[image]

I am interested in a **Site** and **Year** effect on my response variable, but want to account for 'Block ID' as a random effect. Block is clearly nested within each site; however, I have given each block a unique *block_id* name (As the figure suggests), and so may have 'implicit nesting' built into my dataframe.

The question is whether I can simply include 'block_id' as a random effect on its own, or do I need to explicitly define the nesting structure between 'block_id' and 'site' for gam() to run appropriately?

Versions of this question have been asked, but I can't seem to relate it to my particular problem.

[glm example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386227/random-effect-implicitly-nested-in-a-fixed-effect)

[gam example 1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430417/how-to-formulate-nested-random-effects-in-gam)

[gam example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348897/adding-two-random-effects-within-a-factor-gam)

A brief reprex is below, code chunk 1 creates data with uneven sampling of 'block_id' across years and sites. code chunk 2 shows my attempt at using gam() to model results

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mgcv)


#################################
#################################

## Clunky, but generates fake data roughly like I have:


## cell id's
cells <- data.frame(
  site = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 5),
  block.temp = rep(seq(1, 5, 1), 3)
) %>%
  mutate(block = paste0(site, "_", block.temp)) %>%
  select(-block.temp)


## setup year and area sampling
d <- data.frame(
  year = rep(c(2012, 2013, 2014), each = 1000),
  site = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 1000)
)


## Fill in uneven amounts of sampling of block_id by site
site.names <- unique(cells$site)


for (i in 1:length(site.names)) {
  cells.temp <- cells$block[cells$site == site.names[i]]

  d$block_id[d$site == site.names[i]] <- sample(cells.temp, 1000, replace = TRUE)
}


d <- d %>%
  mutate(
    block_id = as.factor(block_id),
    site = as.factor(site),
    response.var = runif(3000, 20,60)
  )


table(d$site, d$block_id)
```

Below I first include a lme4::lmer() model specification where **block_id** is explicitly defined as nested within **site**

Then two options for a specification with gam given the way I have coded block_id in my data. Is the first **gam1** appropriate?

```
glm1 = lmer(response.var ~ site + year + (1|site:block_id), data = d)


## Is this one correct?
gam1 = gam(response.var ~ site + s(year, k = 3) + s(block_id, bs = 're'), data = d)


gam2 = gam(response.var ~ site + s(year, k = 3) + s(block_id, by = site, bs = 're'), data = d)


summary(gam1)
summary(gam2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little rusty on my {lme4} syntax, but the specification you use there isn't estimating separate effects of a variance per `site` and a variance per `block_id` within site, at least as far as I can recollect.

As such, I think the equivalent model in `gam()` is:

```r
m <- gam(response.var ~ site + year + s(block_id, bs = 're'), data = d, method = "REML")
```

It's not quite the same; `lmer()` detects some rank deficiency and drops the `year` effect so there are some subtle differences but:

```r
> ranef(glm1)
$`site:block_id`
        (Intercept)
A:A_1 -0.1539891045
A:A_2  0.2353362669
A:A_3  0.1003993708
A:A_4 -0.0699466347
A:A_5 -0.1117998985
B:B_1 -0.1781176150
B:B_2  0.0727643997
B:B_3  0.0127993045
B:B_4 -0.0129643181
B:B_5  0.1055182290
C:C_1  0.1870077165
C:C_2  0.2821937644
C:C_3 -0.0882142162
C:C_4 -0.0002309663
C:C_5 -0.3807562984

with conditional variances for “site:block_id”
```

and

```r
> data.frame(`(Intercept)` = coef(m)[grepl("s(block_id)", names(coef(m)), fixed = TRUE)], check.names = FALSE)
                 (Intercept)
s(block_id).1  -0.1538140720
s(block_id).2   0.2350678304
s(block_id).3   0.1002870399
s(block_id).4  -0.0698668742
s(block_id).5  -0.1116739242
s(block_id).6  -0.1779188819
s(block_id).7   0.0726834196
s(block_id).8   0.0127859331
s(block_id).9  -0.0129484046
s(block_id).10  0.1053979339
s(block_id).11  0.1868009316
s(block_id).12  0.2818730608
s(block_id).13 -0.0881112529
s(block_id).14 -0.0002306384
s(block_id).15 -0.3803321011
```

Dropping the `year` term from the GAM makes the models effectively the same:

```r
> m0 <- gam(response.var ~ site + s(block_id, bs = 're'), data = d, method = "REML")
> data.frame(`(Intercept)` = coef(m0)[grepl("s(block_id)", names(coef(m0)), fixed = TRUE)], check.names = FALSE)
                 (Intercept)
s(block_id).1  -0.1540066503
s(block_id).2   0.2353631761
s(block_id).3   0.1004106310
s(block_id).4  -0.0699546303
s(block_id).5  -0.1118125265
s(block_id).6  -0.1781375363
s(block_id).7   0.0727725172
s(block_id).8   0.0128006447
s(block_id).9  -0.0129659135
s(block_id).10  0.1055302878
s(block_id).11  0.1870284447
s(block_id).12  0.2822259128
s(block_id).13 -0.0882245380
s(block_id).14 -0.0002309992
s(block_id).15 -0.3807988204
```

Looking at the variance components these models seem effectively equivalent from that perspective too

```r
> gam.vcomp(m0)

Standard deviations and 0.95 confidence intervals:

               std.dev       lower     upper
s(block_id)  0.4157148  0.06103053  2.831678
scale       11.6121233 11.32129661 11.910421

Rank: 2/2
> summary(glm1)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: response.var ~ site + year + (1 | site:block_id)
   Data: d

REML criterion at convergence: 23226.2

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.73795 -0.86059 -0.03097  0.86817  1.80403 

Random effects:
 Groups        Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 site:block_id (Intercept)   0.1728  0.4157 
 Residual                  134.8418 11.6121 
Number of obs: 3000, groups:  site:block_id, 15

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  39.9943     0.4116  97.163
siteB        -0.1622     0.5822  -0.279
siteC        -0.7978     0.5823  -1.370

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
      (Intr) siteB 
siteB -0.707       
siteC -0.707  0.500
fit warnings:
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient
```

So, assuming the model you want is the `lmer` one I think the GAM version I showed is as close as you'll get to it.

Comment: Thank you! Just to clarify: when I'm using my actual dataset, the lmer specification (glm1) does not drop the year term - so maybe this behavior is an artifact of how I 'simulated' data for the example? With that said, assuming that the lmer specification is the one that I want, and that 'year' is retained in the final model -  you are suggesting that your model "m" is the closes gam() specification? (as opposed to 'm0')

Comment: Yes, you are not using the nesting operator `block_id | site` so `site:block_id` is equivalent to `block_id` given the way you have coded `block_id`. Including `year` doesn't change anything as that is independent of the random effects terms, just add it back in to the `gam()` - I removed it because the other terms had larger differences to the `lmer()` model if I kept `year` in the `gam()` one and I wanted to illustrate the random effect structures were resulting in the same model fits, essentially.

Comment: Hello! Quick question @GavinSimpson, does s(site,year, bs='re') imply all the same sites are present in every year (crossed design)? Assuming both are factors.

Comment: @Nate no, it will estimate effects for the columns of `model.matrix( ~ site:year - 1, data = foo)` (IIRC; I think the -1 is needed so we get the dummy coding). So you'll get estimates for the combinations of `site` and `year` that are present in the data. Note that if you want to predict at (site, year) pairs *not* in the data, you need to have those sites/years coded as levels of the respective factor **and** specify `drop.unused.levels = FALSE` when you call `gam()` etc so that it retains the original levels allowing you to predict for an unobserved (site, year) pair.